# Stop settimeout from firing after showing up modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a page which reloads after 10 seconds to display new records, and i do it using a simple settimeout function:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
var timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            location.reload();
        }, 10000);
        timeout();
});
```

Each record in the datatable has one button for displaying a modal with detailed information:

```
<div class="panel-body">
        <div class="dataTable_wrapper">

            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="exemplo">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Visualizar</th>
                        <th>Matrícula Responsável</th>                        
                        <th>Data Solicitação</th>     
                        <th>Status</th>                   
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                    @if (Model != null)
                    {
                        foreach (VivoMais.Repositorio.Entidades.Solicitacao solicitacao in Model.Solicitacoes)
                        {
                            <tr class="odd gradeX">
                                <td><input type="image" src="~/Imagens/Icones/Look.ico" onclick="clearTimeout(timeout);Visualizar('@solicitacao.Id', event);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="margin-left: 30%;" width="28" height="28"></td>
                                <td>@solicitacao.Boleta.Venda.MatriculaConsultor</td>
                                <th>@solicitacao.DataSolicitacao</th>
                                <td>@solicitacao.Status</td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>
    </div>
```

The modal displays, but the parent page still reloads. I tried clearing the timeout on the click event like this:

```
<td><input type="image" src="~/Imagens/Icones/Look.ico" onclick="clearTimeout(timeout);Visualizar('@solicitacao.Id', event);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="margin-left: 30%;" width="28" height="28"></td>
```

How can i stop the parent page from reloading while the modal is being displayed?

I'm using ASP.MVC 5 btw.

Comment: cancel the timer....

Comment: Your `clearTimeout()` doesn't work as you declare `timeout` within the scope of the jQuery document.ready handler. Move that outside. That said, you can avoid the problem completely (and stop reloading the page every 10s and annoying your users) by implementing websockets to keep the client-side data in sync with the server.

Answer (score 0):

Set a flag outside the function and check for status

```
const modalState = 'hidden'

$(document).ready(function () {
var timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        if (modalState === 'hidden') {
         location.reload();
        } else {
          modalState = 'shown'
        }
    }, 10000);
    timeout();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use 'modalViewFlag' and simple if ... else.

> Like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var modalViewFlag = false;

$('#modal-content').on('shown', function() {
    modalViewFlag = true;
})

var timeout = setTimeout(function () {

            if(modalViewFlag == false) {
                location.reload();
            }

        }, 10000);
        timeout();
});
```